# How can I limit the width of title in ExpansionTile in Flutter without affecting content width?

Tags: flutter

I want to create an ExpansionTile but according to the design the icon that collapses or expands the panel has to be right next to the title (text in this case). I haven't been able to get the title instead of expanding to behave like a flex. In the photo you can see in red all the extra space that the title is occupying. I only want the title to have a smaller width, the minimum possible, but the content that expands should occupy all the available width, as shown in the photo.

[image]

I have tried wrapping the title in these ways:

- `Container( constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(20, 30)), color: Colors.red, child: Text( 'This is a title an expanded title', ), ),`
- `SizedBox( width: 10, child: Text( 'This is a title an expanded title', ), ),` : In this case it even shows all the text, even when the size is very small.